# how do I infinitely loop this function without an error?

Tags: python, json, loops

I am trying to loop this function over here to retrieve vaccine alerts via WhatsApp so it constantly monitors the server when I start the script. I tried using the `while True:` command, but this error kept occuring - how cld i fix this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ragz/cowin.py", line 70, in <module>
    vaccine_check()
  File "/Users/ragz/cowin.py", line 35, in vaccine_check
    json_output = json.dumps(available_centers, indent=4)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 234, in dumps
    return cls(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/encoder.py", line 201, in encode
    chunks = list(chunks)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/encoder.py", line 438, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type HTTPError is not JSON serializable
```

If anyone needs it, heres the code -

```
from cowin_api import CoWinAPI
import json
import datetime
import numpy as np 
import os
from twilio.rest import Client
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import io
import requests
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from threading import Thread

state_id = '21'

district_id = '395'

min_age_limit = 18

time = datetime.datetime.now()

cowin = CoWinAPI()


# here im getting the centers and the vaccines
def vaccine_check():

    try:
        available_centers = cowin.get_availability_by_district(district_id)

    #outputing it to a json file and bringing it back

        json_output = json.dumps(available_centers, indent=4)

        f = open(f'tests/vaccinecheck[{time.strftime("%b %d %Y %H|%M")}].json', 'w')

        f.write(json_output)
        f.close()

        with open(f.name) as file:
            data = json.load(file)

        n = np.arange(100)

        for x in np.nditer(n): 

            if data["centers"][x]["sessions"][0]["min_age_limit"] == 45:
                print('')   
            else:
                print(f'[{time.strftime("%b %d %Y %H:%M")}]', data["centers"][x]["name"], '-- vaccines:', data["centers"][x]["sessions"][0]['available_capacity'], '-- age-limit:', data["centers"][x]["sessions"][0]["min_age_limit"])
                if data["centers"][x]["sessions"][0]["available_capacity"] >= 1:
                    twilio_send()
    except IndexError: # catch the error
        pass # pass will basically ignore it

def twilio_send():

    client = Client()

    from_whatsapp_number='whatsapp:twilio api demo num'
        
    to_whatsapp_number='whatsapp:my phone num'

    client.messages.create(body='vaccine available - book now!',
                       from_=from_whatsapp_number,
                       to=to_whatsapp_number)
while True:
    vaccine_check()
```

Comment: It's telling you you have an http error.  So, look at the error, and decide how you want to handle it.  Maybe add a default `except` that will catch everything.

Comment: the `get_availability` function returns an `HTTPError` that is not caught by the `except`

Comment: so how do i add an except that passes EVERYTHING? is there a way? im not sure...

Comment: @trashflutterdev It's just `except:` with nothing after it except the colon.